# Irrespective of any "singular nouns" vs "plural nouns"

Tags: grammar

Can anyone please tell me whether I should use singular or plural nouns after ***irrespective of any*** in the following context? I have searched the Internet and found that both singular and plural nouns are used though plural nouns were more in number.

Here is the context:

Terrorism is a menace. We must come together to end it. Irrespective of any compromise(***s***) the world should take action against those fringe elements.

I have asked this because I come from a non-native english speaking country where it is said by teachers ***"any"*** is always singular. And one more questions if I always use "***any***" with plural nouns with contexts like the one I cited above, will that be always grammatical? I know ***"any***" can be used with singular nouns in a sentence like **"Any man can do it."** My question is different. I want to know if **"any"** with plural nouns is always grammatical in contexts like the one In my example. Could anyone who has good knowledge in the language please answer this?

Comment: *Any* as determiner by no means always determines a singular substantive.  E.g., Gen  47.5 KJV: "and if thou knowest *any men* of activity among them, then make them rulers over my cattle."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you. I have read it before. My question is different.    Should I use plural or singular nouns after "any" in the given context?

Comment: As rhitagawr has already answered you elsewhere {[forum.wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/irrespective-of-any.3409891/)}, " 'Irrespective of' is **irrelevant** in this context. 'Any' can be singular or plural.
'The prisoners were released irrespective of any charges that had been brought against them.' Plural.
'You'll be released irrespective of any crime you may have committed.' "  [bolding mine] Thus your question **is** a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Any can be used for both singular and plural, but it always depends on the sentence it used in. "You can borrow any book you like." "Any ideas on this one?"

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions when they are easy to discover.